# How to return ids with specific values in another column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table USER_ROLE with the format like this.

```
+--------+---------+
|USER_ID | ROLE    |
+--------+---------+
|1       | ADD     |
+--------+---------+
|1       | DELETE  |
+--------+---------+
|1       | VIEW    |
+--------+---------+
|1       | TRANSFER|
+--------+---------+
|2       | ADD     |
+--------+---------+
|2       | DELETE  |
+--------+---------+
|2       | VIEW    |
+--------+---------+
|2       | TRANSFER|
+--------+---------+
|3       | ADD     |
+--------+---------+
|3       | DELETE  |
+--------+---------+
|4       | VIEW    |
+--------+---------+
|4       | TRANSFER|
+--------+---------+
```

I want to find the USER_IDs that have all the below ROLEs.

- ADD
- DELETE
- VIEW

So it should return 1 and 2 from above example.

I managed to get the results with below queries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID 
FROM USER_ROLE r1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USER_ROLE r2 WHERE r2.ROLE = 'ADD' AND r1.USER_ID = r2.USER_ID)
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USER_ROLE r2 WHERE r2.ROLE = 'DELETE' AND r1.USER_ID = r2.USER_ID)
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USER_ROLE r2 WHERE r2.ROLE = 'VIEW' AND r1.USER_ID = r2.USER_ID)
```

and

```
SELECT USER_ID FROM USER_ROLE WHERE ROLE = 'ADD'
INTERSECT SELECT USER_ID FROM USER_ROLE WHERE ROLE = 'DELETE'
INTERSECT SELECT USER_ID FROM USER_ROLE WHERE ROLE = 'VIEW'
```

Can you suggest any simple alternatives to these.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT user_id
FROM
user_role
WHERE role IN('ADD','DELETE','VIEW') 
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING count(*)=3
```

Here is the [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6e856/34) to SqlFiddle

Comment: You could put the link to the fiddle in the main body of the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do it, but your INTERSECT method is probably the simplest. You could also do a proper Pivot.

```
SELECT USER_ID
FROM (
SELECT USER_ID, 
       [ADD] = MAX(CASE WHEN ROLE = 'ADD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       [DELETE] = MAX(CASE WHEN ROLE = 'DELETE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       [VIEW] = MAX(CASE WHEN ROLE = 'VIEW' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM   USER_ROLE AS r1
GROUP  BY USER_ID 
) AS U
WHERE [ADD] = 1 and [DELETE] = 1 and [VIEW] = 1
```